# Is there any way to measure times more precise than with currentTimeMillis() or nanoTime()?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I know you can measure times with currentTimeMillis() or nanoTime() but I would need a more precise measure. Is there any possibility?
Thanks!

Comment: How would an Arduino, running at max 20 MHz, obtain a clock with more than nanosecond precision? That would require a clock with more than 1 GHz.

Comment: What do you need such precision for?

Comment: I don't want it for Arduino, I want it to measure the changes in the accelerometer --> 800MHz

Comment: @Marcos the change must be calculated by the CPU. Thus, you are limited by the rate of the CPU. Unless, of course, you can somehow bypass the CPU and directly write the sensor data in some kind of file / memory location. But then again, to process the data, you need to involve the CPU.

Comment: Thank you very much! Write it as a answer so I can upvote you. @Turing85

Comment: @Marcos [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59490255/4216641).

Comment: How fast is that accelerometer? An Arduino can't, by far, read data at 800 MHz.

Comment: @Erlkoenig the samsung s3 accelerometer's datasheet shows that the maximum rate is 800MHz

Comment: Sure that it's not the bitrate? Can you link the datasheet?

Comment: [link](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) is the odr

Comment: It's 800Hz, not MHz. Off by a factor of a million. I.e. resolution is 1.25ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change must be calculated by the CPU. Thus, you are limited by the rate of the CPU. Unless, of course, you can somehow bypass the CPU and directly write the sensor data in some kind of file / memory location. But then again, to process the data, you need to involve the CPU.